# Close a dropdown when an element within it is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

I'm working on a Notification feature in my app (pretty much like Facebook notifications).

When I click a button in the header navigation, the dropdown opens and shows the notification list. The notification has a `Link` (from `react-router`) in it.

What I need to do is to close the dropdown whenever a `Link` is clicked.

Here's roughly the hierarchy I currently have:

```
Header > Navigation > Button > Dropdown > List > Notification > Link
```

Since the dropdown functionality is used more that once, I've abstracted its behavior away into a HOC that uses render prop:

```js
export default function withDropDown(ClickableElement) {
  return class ClickableDropdown extends PureComponent {
    static propTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      showOnInit: PropTypes.bool,
    };

    static defaultProps = {
      showOnInit: false,
    };

    state = {
      show: !!this.props.showOnInit,
    };

    domRef = createRef();

    componentDidMount() {
      document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleGlobalClick);
    }

    toggle = show => {
      this.setState({ show });
    };

    handleClick = () => this.toggle(true);

    handleGlobalClick = event => {
      if (this.domRef.current && !this.domRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
        this.toggle(false);
      }
    };

    render() {
      const { children, ...props } = this.props;
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <ClickableElement {...props} onClick={this.handleClick} />
          {this.state.show && children(this.domRef)}
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

The HOC above encloses the `Button` component, so I have:

```js
const ButtonWithDropdown = withDropdown(Button);

class NotificationsHeaderDropdown extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(notification),
    load: PropTypes.func,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    data: [],
    load: () => {},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.load();
  }

  renderDropdown = ref => (
    <Dropdown ref={ref}>
      {data.length > 0 && <List items={this.props.data} />}
      {data.length === 0 && <EmptyList />}
    </Dropdown>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonWithDropdown count={this.props.data.length}>
        {this.renderDropdown}
      </ButtonWithDropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

`List` and `Notification` are both dumb functional components, so I'm not posting their code here. `Dropdown` is pretty much the same, with the difference it uses [ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

What I really need is to call that `.toggle()` method from `ClickableDropdown`  created by the HOC to be called whenever I click on a `Link` on the list.

Is there any way of doing this without passing that `.toggle()` method down the `Button > Dropdown > List > Notification > Link` subtree?

I'm using `redux`, but I'm not sure this is the kind of thing I'd put on the store.

Or should I handle this imperatively using the DOM API, by changing the implementation of `handleGlobalClick` from `ClickableDropdown`?

---

### Edit:

I'm trying with the imperative approach, so I've changed the `handleGlobalClick` method:

```js
const DISMISS_KEY = 'dropdown';

function contains(current, element) {
  if (!current) {
    return false;
  }

  return current.contains(element);
}

function isDismisser(dismissKey, current, element) {
  if (!element || !contains(current, element)) {
    return false;
  }

  const shouldDismiss = element.dataset.dismiss === dismissKey;

  return shouldDismiss || isDismisser(dismissKey, current, element.parentNode);
}

// Then...
handleGlobalClick = event => {
  const containsEventTarget = contains(this.domRef.current, event.target);
  const shouldDismiss = isDismisser(
    DISMISS_KEY,
    this.domRef.current,
    event.target
  );

  if (!containsEventTarget || shouldDismiss) {
    this.toggle(false);
  }

  return true;
};
```

Then I changed the `Link` to include a `data-dismiss` property:

```js
<Link
  to={url}
  data-dismiss="dropdown"
>
  ...
</Link>
```

Now the dropdown is closed, but I'm not redirected to the provided `url` anymore.

I tried to defer the execution of `this.toggle(false)` using `requestAnimationFrame` and `setTimeout`, but it didn't work either.

---

### Solution:

Based on the answer by @streletss bellow, I came up with the following solution:

In order to be as generic as possible, I created a `shouldHideOnUpdate` prop in the `ClickableDropdown` dropdown component, whose Hindley-Milner-ish signature is:

```js
shouldHideOnUpdate :: Props curr, Props prev => (curr, prev) -> Boolean
```

Here's the `componentDidUpdate` implementation:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.shouldHideOnUpdate(this.props, prevProps)) {
    this.toggle(false);
  }
}
```

This way, I didn't need to use the `withRouter` HOC directly in my `withDropdown` HOC.

So, I lifted the responsibility of defining the condition for hiding the dropdown to the caller, which is my case is the `Navigation` component, where I did something like this:

```js
const container = compose(withRouter, withDropdown);
const ButtonWithDropdown = container(Button);


function routeStateHasChanged(currentProps, prevProps) {
  return currentProps.location.state !== prevProps.location.state;
}

// ... then

  render() {
    <ButtonWithDropdown shouldHideOnUpdate={routeStateHasChanged}>
      {this.renderDropdown}
    </ButtonWithDropdown>
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you could simply make use of `withRouter` HOC and check if `this.props.location.pathname` has changed when `componentDidUpdate`:

```
export default function withDropDown(ClickableElement) {
  class ClickableDropdown extends Component {
    // ...

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
        this.toggle(false);
      }
    }

    // ...
  };

  return withRouter(ClickableDropdown)
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea! However, the my notifications can redirect the user to the same page he is in, keeping the same `pathname`, only changing the route `state`. If I change the conditional to check for `state`, it works. But I'm afraid this would be too generic, don't you think? Should I try to mix what you're suggesting here with the approach given by @Root in his/her answer, using the route state?

Comment: Yeah, mixing both approaches makes sense

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there any way of doing this without passing that .toggle() method down the Button > Dropdown > List > Notification > Link subtree?

In the question, you mention that you are using redux.So I assume that you store showOnInit in redux.We don't usually store a function in redux.In toggle function,I think you should dispatch an CHANGE_SHOW action to change the showOnInit in redux, then pass the show data not the function to the children component.Then after reducer dispatch,the react will change “show” automatically.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_SHOW:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        showOnInit: action.text
      })
    ...
    default:
      return state
  }
```

#### Link element and data pass

Use the property in Link-to,not data-...Like this:

```
 <Link
  to={{
     pathname: url,
     state:{dismiss:"dropdown"}
     }}
/>
```

And the state property will be found in this.props.location.

## give context a little try(not recommend)

It may lead your project to instable and some other problems.(https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype)

First,define context

```
const MyContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);
```

Second,define pass value

```
<MyContext.Provider value={this.toggle}>
```

Then,get the value in the nested component

```
<div value={this.context} />
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not storing `showOnInit` on redux, because it is statically defined by the application. I'm not sure if I'm comfortable doing so, because this is not a "global" property. The idea of using route state is interesting though.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos While, redux is used to solve this kind of problem.:)And I offer another option:context.But I have to say, it doesn't work well like redux.

Comment: I appreciate your insights. I used the idea of route state in my final solution, but @streletss' solution made me feel more comfortable, so that's why I rewarded him instead, since SO doesn't allow for splitting bounty AFAIK.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Oh,it's fine.Glad to help you.:)